# get error because of HRESULT , LARGE_INTEGER and DWORD in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, cuda, video-encoding

I had a sample code for CUDA VIDEO ENCODING  which originally written for windows, after preparing Make file and trying to compile it, it come to error because of HRESULT , LARGE_INTEGER and DWORD data type that they are specific to windows. how can I overcome this problem ?

```
LARGE_INTEGER m_liUserTime0, m_liKernelTime0;
DWORD m_dwStartTime;
```

is there any alternative for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define these types yourself:

```
typedef unsigned long long LARGE_INTEGER;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef long HRESULT;
```

Comment: `LARGE_INTEGER` is a bit more complicated.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RetiredNinja - But shouldn't the above be sufficient if you don't need to use it as a structure ie the `HighPart`, `LowPart` and `QuadPart`?

Comment: Since `LARGE_INTEGER` is a Windows API only thing I would suppose it's unlikely to be used for anything in linux, but if that's the case then surely it's better to just exclude that platform specific code when not compiling for Windows.  I suppose we'll see if there's a new question of "Hey, how do I implement (Windows API Specific Function) in linux in a couple of days. :)